# How to edit time without seconds in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

##### Is is possible to show only hours and minutes when editing a time cell?

Something which has bothered me for a long time: I have a sheet to hold my working times.

Everytime I want to change a time shown as `10:25` to lets say `10:27` and I go into edit mode (<kbd>F2</kbd> or doubleclick) it gets shown as `10:25:00`.

It would be much more comfortable if it would be also `10:25` in edit mode (without seconds), because I only need to delete the minutes with backspace. Util now I have to use the arrow keys or have to delete the seconds also.

May sound like a tiny or irrelevant problem, but if you do it everyday, it's annoying and time consuming.

Comment: I'm also a developer, so even if it requires any kind of programming or complex configuration it would be fine.

Comment: You should be able to just overwrite the cell with your value (e.g. 10:27) without entering the cell's edit mode.  This is 5 key-presses, same as `F2+del+del+new value+new value`, and no messy going to mouse or double-clicking or function keys to worry about.

Comment: To clarify my question: generally I'm wondering why it is not possible to edit only hours and minutes. 

How often someone **really** needs seconds in a time cell? If someone needs to use also seconds he could enter hh:mm:ss, and if he edit he should see hh:mm:ss

I wish there was an option to enable this behavior. Maybe I submit a feature request to MS .. ;-)

Comment: **@dav** You convinced me (because I have to ;-). But it need 7 to 9 keystrokes: `F2 + del + del + del (:ss) + del (m) + del(m) + new value + new value + enter` ;-)

Comment: **@dav** final thoughts: To type in a colon (again) after numbers make my fingers tired, so I dont like to input the new time again. To edit with filled hh:mm I only need 4 to 6 keystrokes: `F2 +  del (m) [+ del(m)] + new value [+ new value] + enter`

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/651026/43613) indicates, you might be able to change how dates are displayed in the formula bar by changing your region/language settings for your computer, but I don't believe that you can change the time display.

Assuming that this spreadsheet is within your control and that adjusting minutes is among the more common tasks that you perform, you could solve this by calculating the time off of two other cells.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 25 | 10:25 |

Columns A and B are simply the numbers you enter and edit. Column C would contain the following formula: `=TIME(A1,B1,0)`

Comment: Thank you, this would be a good workaround. However I dont want to introduce additional columns. See updated question.